# How can i get the following output using linux sorting?

Tags: text-processing, sort

Input:

```
C_ABC_066.T02
C_BC_066.T02
C_ABC_066.T01
C_BC_066.T01
```

Desired output after Linux sort

```
C_BC_066.T01
C_ABC_066.T01
C_BC_066.T02
C_ABC_066.T02
```

Comment: Could you please say something about what piece of the data that you're sorting on. It looks as if you're sorting on the last bit of each string, after the dot, but you don't say anything about that or what the result would be if e.g. `066` was different in one line (like `065`).

Comment: only the second field i.e BC/ABC and Last field T01/T02/T03/T04...... will be different rest will be the same. These are filemasks of text files. I just want to sort based on these two fields.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how you are sorting. Why `C_ABC_066.T01` is after `C_BC_066.T01`? Usually `ABC` comes before `BC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$ sort -t. -k2,2 -k1,1r data
C_BC_066.T01
C_ABC_066.T01
C_BC_066.T02
C_ABC_066.T02
```

That says to use `.` as the separator (`-t.`), then sort by the second field (`-k2,2`), then by the first field in reverse (`-k1,1r`). I'd expect `ABC` would come before `BC` in next to any locale, so we need that reverse sort here.